# Finding divisors of a number

Tags: java, beginner, mathematics

This code finds all the divisors of a given number.  Can it be shortened?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNum2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number :  ");
        long y=x.nextInt(),i;
        System.out.print("Divisors of "+y+" = 1 , ");

        for( i=2;i<y;i++){
            long z=y%i;
            if(z!=0)continue;
                System.out.print(i+" , ");

        }System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you start with i = 2? Why not change it to i = 1?

Comment: @Tag I suppose that's mainly because the smallest prime number, according to primality as defined by modern mathematicians, is 2.

Comment: @Dex'ter If a user enters `1` as the input then `1` is repeated multiple times in the output. This is, of course, still technically correct. By modifying the loop to start at `1` and removing the last 4 characters from the end of the Divisors string we end up with cleaner output.  In hindsight, I was being pedantic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This code could do with some editing...

First of all is the spacing. It is absolutely horrible (we will fix that after the edits).

Also, the naming is horrible. `Scanner x` could be `scanner` and `y` could be `num`. As for z, it is completely unnecessary:

> ```
> for (i = 2; i < y; i++) {
>     long z = y % i;
>     if (z != 0)
>         continue;
>     System.out.print(i + " , ");
> }
> ```

Becomes:

```
for (i = 2; i < y; i++) {
    if (y % i != 0)
        continue;
    System.out.print(i + " , ");
}
```

The program can do without the continue statement:

```
for (i = 2; i < y; i++) {
    if (y % i == 0)
        System.out.print(i + " , ");
}
```

It's also a good idea to put braces around statements in an `if` statement, even when there is only one:

```
for (i = 2; i < y; i++) {
    if (y % i == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " , ");
    }
}
```

You are also wasting time going through `for` loops doing nothing. After all, `num`'s largest factor before itself possible is `num / 2`, which makes it more efficient doing it like this:

```
for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " , ");
    }
}
```

I also noticed:

> ```
>  public static void main(String args[])
> ```

It is better to put `[]` at the type (`String`):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

But the main problem is that you have a memory leak. It could be solved by closing the `Scanner`:

```
scanner.close();
```

### Final code:

Your final code will look like this:

```
public class PrimeNum2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number :  ");
        long num = scanner.nextInt(), i;
        System.out.print("Divisors of " + num + " = 1 , ");
        for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                System.out.print(i + " , ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Condition in for loop should be i <=num/2 and not i <num/2. Test with num = 6. With above code: divisors of 6 will print 1, 2, 6 as loop starts from 2 and not check 3

Comment: @prashantsunkari Good catch, will fix.

Comment: The only problem wiil be the special case of the number 1. Will print 'Divisors of 1 = 1 , 1'.

Comment: `i` should be local to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 9):

You can actually stop checking at `Math.sqrt(num)` because the current divisor always yields its conjugate:

```
for (i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " , ");
        if (i != num/i) {
            System.out.print(num/i + " , ");
        }
    }
}
```

We have to add an extra check, however, to avoid duplicate output in the case where `num` is a perfect square.

Comment: `Math.sqrt` is an expensive operation. You should not call that function more often than necessary.

Answer (score 6):

```
for( i=2; i <= (y / 2); i++)
{
    long z=y%i;
    if(z!=0)continue;
    System.out.print(i+" , ");
}
```

This `for` loop can be shortened, since a number's largest divisor (other than itself) will always be \$\frac{1}{2}\$. So instead of `i < y`, you could do `i <= (y/2)`, assuming you are only counting integers, which you are since you say divisors.

\$136\$: largest divisor - \$68\$ (\$\le \frac{1}{2}\$ of \$136\$)

\$99\$: largest divisor - \$33\$ (\$\le \frac{1}{2}\$ of \$99\$)

Answer (score 1):

As far as efficiency is concerned you should first generate a list of divisors 
12-> {2,2,3} then group them -> {{2,2},{3}} then apply product of sets (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714108/cartesian-product-of-arbitrary-sets-in-java)).

This way you never check for divisors above n^(0.5) and make your search for divisors very efficient.